# How to test a scenario when initial Stripe subscription creation is successful and then the card expires for the next billing period

Tags: stripe-payments

Imagine the following case:

1. I buy a monthly subscription - subscription is successfully created in Stripe.
2. When the next billing period comes, my card is already expired (or there is no fund in it) so the renewal fails.

I had an idea to use a valid test card first and then create another payment method with an expired card. However, Stripe won't allow me to add that kind of payment methods.

How can I test this scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe has a great test card[1] for this kind of error. You can add it to a customer but it will fail any payment.

> `4000000000000341` Attaching this card to a Customer object succeeds, but attempts to charge the customer fail.

For this kind of test, I typically create a customer, attach that card to them, and create a subscription with a trial period[2] of 10 seconds. After the trial is over, I manually finalize and try to take payment on the invoice to cause the renewal failure.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/testing

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-trial_end

Comment: Great! Thanks! I somehow failed to find that in the docs :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have found a work around, I couldn't find a dedicated solution.

I have used test clocks, stripe cli.

Steps:

1. Add a customer and attach test clock.
2. Complete the payment , I used session checkout.
3. Then open the stripe dashboard, go to customers, then delete the payment method (or edit to a card with the error condition you want to test for).
4. Forward the test clock accordingly (month, year).
5. As the payment method is not attached invoice.payment_failed is triggered.
6. Test weather your code handles it situation properly.

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPoHR.png),[Step5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pmkd.png),[Final Dashboard Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YHZS.png)

This question is the same and shows the bug in test clocks.

[I want to test my project if it handles the condition where the subscription payment fails after one billing cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76747342/i-want-to-test-my-project-if-it-handles-the-condition-where-the-subscription-pay)