# I want to test my project if it handles the condition where the subscription payment fails after one billing cycle

Tags: stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-test-mode

Using Stripe and node.js

I have tested the following way:

- Added a test clock set to the current time.
- Entered the expiration date of the card to next month.
- Then forwarded the test clock to a year into the future.

Still shows that the payment was a success for the next billing cycle.

In the following image you can see:

- Under Payment methods, the card expires Aug 2023
- Under invoices, you can see that the bill is successfully paid for next year(2024).
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV7zu.png)

I need steps to test the project for the above-mentioned situation.

Comment: For any one looking for the answer, I found it, manually delete the test card from the dashboard and then forward the test clock then the invoice.payment_failed web hook is trigged along with all the appropriate webhooks. If any one finds a better solution please  add it .